# memory swap to disk in Java JVM

Tags: java, memory, jvm, swap

I am using 64-bit Linux and Java JVM. I want to confirm if the memory used by JVM is smaller than physical memory size of the machine, there will be no disk memory swap by OS?

Comment: You mean setting `-Xmx` for the JVM?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not necessarily true.  Physical memory is shared by all processes, as well as by a bunch of other kernel things (e.g. the disk cache).  So the amount of virtual memory used by your application is not the only consideration.

Comment: you could just configure a linux machine with absolutely no swap, but thats plain dangerous.

Comment: indeed it is not. I tend to always have swap disabled by default. RAM is cheap this days and your active processes should operate on RAM on a server anyway. Having swap will only delay problems like memory leaking and not-so-good-tunned gc parameters

Comment: Hi Oli, if there are free physical RAM, then there should not be swap, correct? Or swap may be triggered under other conditions (even if there are free physical RAM)? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa it should not happen. Swapping is not supposed to occur when is not necesary. But as I said, in a server, you should have enoguh RAM for your processes. Just have no swap at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can start your java application with the jvm argument -Xmx512m wich will tell the jvm to use a max of 512MB of ram for your heap. Take in account also that there exists another parameter for thread stack size -Xss512k. So the amount of memory that your jvm will use will be the max heap + (threadCount * threadStackSize) + some more ram for JIT compilation and GC datastructures depending on the GC collector that you use

Having this into account you can make sure your jvm wont use more ram than what is present in your machine

Comment: Thanks David, do you know under which condition memory swap will be triggered?

Comment: When the kernel decides it so I think(tm), you can not control that. I suppose the OS is smart enough to swap areas of memory ocupied that are least accesed first.