# Why does Spring Boot WEB take to respond more faster?

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, centos7

I usually use Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate + Postgres.

At the end of the development of a WEB application I compile in Jar, then I run it directly with Java and then I do reverse proxy with Apache (httpd).

I have noticed that when starting there are no problems or latency, when accessing the website it works very quickly, but when several hours pass without anyone making a request to the server and then I want to access I must wait at least 20 seconds until the server responds, after this I can continue to access the site normally.

Why does this happen ?, It is as if Spring were in standby mode every time it detects that it has no load of requests, but I am not sure if it is so or is a problem. If it's some native spring functionality, how can I disable it?

Although I need to use a little more memory in idle state I want the answers to be fast regardless of whether it is loaded or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, it is likely that while your webapp is sitting idle, other programs on your server is using memory and cause the JVM memory to be swapped to disk.

When you then access the webapp again, the OS has to swap that JVM memory back into RAM, one page at a time. That takes time, but once the memory is back in RAM, your webapp will run normally.

Unfortunately, the way Java memory works, swapping JVM memory to disk is *very* bad for performance. That is an issue for most languages that rely on garbage collectors to free memory. Languages with manual memory management, e.g. C++ code, will usually not be hit as badly, when memory is swapped to disk, because memory use is more "focused" in those languages.

**Solution:** If my guess at the cause of your problem is correct, reconfigure your server so the JVM memory won't be swapped to disk.

Note that when I say server, I mean the physical machine. The "other programs", that your JVM is fighting for memory, might be running in different VMs, i.e. not in the same OS.

Comment: Thanks, i found information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464642/memory-swap-to-disk-in-java-jvm and here http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/the-most-important-jvm-memory-tuning-parameter-and-how-to-ace-it/